# In Playwright, in need to reuse an uuid defined in a test in another test

Tags: typescript, e2e-testing, playwright

I have two separated tests (into two separated files, run in parallel) that create two distinct companies in my test environment.

For some later tests in need to actually know the uuid of both companies, I wish to kind of store them in a thing that can be used in all the tests that come after those creation test.

I know playwright fixtures exist but it doesn't seems like something that can be used in my case, as it didn't seems that i can redefine a fixture inside a test ? (If I can I missed the info, but it is mentioned nowhere in the documentation)

I also know that it come against the "each test must be separated from each other" rule/mentality but the uuid-thing is a business constraint in my case.

Comment: Please post your code so far.

Answer (score 0):

I discovered today that I can use the .env for this. I can alter an environment variable with playwright (which I assumed was a readonly variable, but it is, in fact, not).

I create my company, then set my variable and continue my test, end the first test and then retrieve the uuid in the second test. it is great !
As the environment is reset in the end of the playwright test process, I don't have to clean after.

I didn't post the setter and getter because they are described in playwright documentation, but I can if needed.

My .env :

```
UUID_COMPANY_1=uuid_of_the_first_company
```

My code :

```
test.describe('Create and test stuff in my company 1', () => {
  // a personnal context I need to set up - irrelevant
  const context = getInitializedContext();
  
  // The first test
  test('Create and configure Company 1', async ({ page }, workerInfo) => {
    
    // my test to know if the environment was reset between two sessions of test, which it was
    console.log(retrieveUuidCompany1());
    
    const email = new emailManager();
    const baseUrl = workerInfo.project.use.baseURL;
    let locatorConfiguration = retrieveLocatorConfiguration(context);

    // Create a company with a first user
    await logInAdmin(page, baseUrl, locatorConfiguration);
    
    
    // this function return the uuid and a bunch of stuff
    const companyAndFirstUser = await createCompanyAndFirstUser(
      page,
      locatorConfiguration,
      USER_1,
      COMPANY_1_CONFIGURATION,
      email,
      context,
    );

    const uuidNewCompany = companyAndFirstUser['uuidCompany'];
    
    //set the uuid I want in the .env
    setUuidCompany1(uuidNewCompany); 
    //verify the set functioned 
    console.log(retrieveUuidCompany1());
    
    // a bunch of my irrelevant test code lied here
  });
  
  // The second test
  test('Uuid company 1', async ({ page }, workerInfo) => {
    // verification the environment is still not reset here
    console.log(retrieveUuidCompany1());
  });
});
```